# In JSS how do I support both secure and open GraphQL endpoints?

Tags: jss, authentication, graphql

In my `JSS` application, how do I support both `authenticated` (logged in) `GraphQL` endpoints and in-secure (public/open) GraphQL endpoints?

The example `Angular` application shows the usage of only one public endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this from an Angular perspective and using the sample JSS Angular application as a point of reference. The samples below assume you're using Apollo for your queries.

## JSS Configuration

Firstly in your JSS configuration we setup two endpoints.

- One that requires a Sitecore user to be logged in.

```
/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/security/systemService
```

- One that is open and can be called by any anonymous user.

```
/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/security/publicService
```

```
<endpoints>
 <myGraphQLEndpoint url="/api/mysecureapi" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.DatabaseAwareGraphQLEndpoint, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.NetFxHost" resolve="true">
<url>$(url)</url>

<enabled>true</enabled>
<enableSubscriptions>true</enableSubscriptions>

<!-- lock down the endpoint when deployed to content delivery -->
<graphiql role:require="ContentDelivery">false</graphiql>
<enableSchemaExport role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableSchemaExport>
<enableStats role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableStats>
<enableCacheStats role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableCacheStats>
<disableIntrospection role:require="ContentDelivery">true</disableIntrospection>

<schema hint="list:AddSchemaProvider">
  ... INSERT GRAPHQL SCHEMAS HERE
</schema>

<!-- Enables the 'jss' graph nodes that are preformatted to use with JSS rendering components, and the datasource resolving queries for JSS -->
<extenders hint="list:AddExtender">
  <layoutExtender type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.GraphQL.JssExtender, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.GraphQL" resolve="true" />
</extenders>

<!-- Determines the security of the service. 'publicService' is open to anonymous access, but requires an SSC API key. -->
<security ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/security/systemService" />

<!-- Determines how performance is logged for the service. Defaults are defined in Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.config -->
<performance ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/performance/standard" />
</myGraphQLEndpoint>

<myOpenGraphQLEndpoint url="/api/myopenapi" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.DatabaseAwareGraphQLEndpoint, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.NetFxHost" resolve="true">
<url>$(url)</url>

<enabled>true</enabled>
<enableSubscriptions>true</enableSubscriptions>

<!-- lock down the endpoint when deployed to content delivery -->
<graphiql role:require="ContentDelivery">false</graphiql>
<enableSchemaExport role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableSchemaExport>
<enableStats role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableStats>
<enableCacheStats role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableCacheStats>
<disableIntrospection role:require="ContentDelivery">true</disableIntrospection>

<schema hint="list:AddSchemaProvider">
    ... INSERT GRAPHQL SCHEMAS HERE
</schema>

<!-- Determines the security of the service. 'publicService' is open to anonymous access, but requires an SSC API key. -->
<security ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/security/publicService" />

<performance ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/performance/standard" />
</myOpenGraphQLEndpoint>
```

## Angular Code

(Based on the example [jss-graphql.module.ts](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/samples/angular/src/app/jss-graphql.module.ts) )

#### 1) Inside of jss-graphql.module.ts

Introduce 2 Apollo clients:

```
 private readonly apollo: Apollo,          // Secure
 private readonly apolloOpenApi: Apollo,   // Anonymous, no Auth required
```

Both Apollo clients will be initialised once (each) within this typescript file.

Create two environment variables in your application:

- environment.graphQLEndpoint = /api/myopenapi
- environment.graphQLOpenEndpoint = /api/mysecureapi

Initialise the secure connection as normal:

```
  const batchHttp = this.httpLink.create({ uri: environment.graphQLEndpoint, withCredentials: true });

  ...

  this.apollo.create({
  link: automaticPersistHttp,
  cache: cache,
  ssrMode: isPlatformServer(this.platformId),
  ssrForceFetchDelay: 100,
});
```

Initialise the insecure connection with a named value for the apollo client (in this case 'Open'):

```
const batchHttp = this.httpLink.create({ uri: environment.graphQLOpenEndpoint, withCredentials: true });

...

this.apolloOpenApi.create({
  link: automaticPersistHttp,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  ssrMode: isPlatformServer(this.platformId),
  ssrForceFetchDelay: 50,
}, 'Open');
```

The named client will be used to differentiate the two.

#### 2) Inside of jss-graphql.service.ts   (Based on example [jss-graphql.service.ts](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/samples/angular/src/app/jss-graphql.service.ts))

In your constructor make sure that both Apollo clients get injected.

```
   constructor(
private readonly apollo: Apollo,
private readonly apolloOpenApi: Apollo,
private readonly sitecoreContext: JssContextService,
@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private readonly platformId: string,
) {
this.isEditingOrPreviewingAndSsr =
  isPlatformServer(this.platformId) &&
  this.sitecoreContext.state.value.sitecore.context.pageState !== 'normal';
}
```

Introduce a new function called queryOpen that will allow you to call the non-secure apollo client.

```
queryOpen<T, V = R>(options: QueryOptions<V> & JssGraphQLOptions): Observable<ApolloQueryResult<T>> {

...

const observable = this.apolloOpenApi.use('Open').query<T>(options);

...

return observable;
```

}

All other secure queries can go via the original query for Authenticated calls inside of jss-graphql.service.ts   (Based on example [jss-graphql.service.ts](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/samples/angular/src/app/jss-graphql.service.ts)

3)  Each component that makes a query will now be able to call either queryOpen or query depending on its authentication needs.

```
  this.query$ = this.graphQLService.queryOpen({
    query: ComponentQuery,
    variables: data
  });

 this.query$ = this.graphQLService.query({
    query: ComponentQuery,
    variables: data
  });
```